# AWK Print $2 Breaking Bash Args

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to capture the output from an EC2 command with AWK. The AWK portion works and the EC2 command work. The problem is, I pass arguments to the script and one of them conflicts with the style of AWK. Specifically `print $2`

Proper segment is

```
cmd="/opt/aws/bin/ec2-run-instances -O $secid  -W $seckey $ami  -n $1 -g $secg -k $sshkey -t $instsize -z $2 | awk '/^INSTANCE/ {print $2}'
```

As you can see, I need that print $2 to capture the EC2 instance id. Is there a workaround without changing my arg format?

Thanks!

```
RESERVATION     r-******      ********    www.abc.com
INSTANCE        i-****      ami-*****
```

Comment: Please provide a sample EC2 output.

Comment: What do you mean it "conflicts"? As long as it's properly quoted (which it looks like this is) it should work fine.

Comment: I have no issues with `ec2-describe-instances | awk '/^INSTANCE/ {print $2}'`

Comment: @RomanNewaza As I mentioned I am passing an argument to the script using $1 and $2 inside the script. It  conflicts.

Comment: @Publiccert Pipe it instead of arguments and read it from your shell script

Comment: Added whole bash command.

Comment: How is the `cmd` variable used?

Comment: @icktoofay I'm honestly not sure what you're talking about. I pass the script to cmd, then execute it. And for your previous comment...I'm even more confused as to what you're talking about.

Comment: what are you passing in as `$2` to your script?

Comment: @EugenConstantinDinca us-east-1a from the CLI.

Comment: @Publiccert: I'm asking how you're executing it, since avoiding putting it in a variable would probably make it work.

Comment: See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
result=$(/opt/aws/bin/ec2-run-instances -O $secid  -W $seckey $ami  -n $1 -g $secg -k $sshkey -t $instsize -z $2 | awk '/^INSTANCE/ {print $2}')
for instance_id in $result; do echo $instance_id; done
```

Comment: Well sir, you nailed it! Thank you!

Comment: I had a side-question: how is the instance_id being established? Is that a return from AWS? Thanks!

Comment: Yea, you get it from $result. This is how for loop works. You defined it after `for` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you just need to escape it for awk so that shell doesn't replace `$1`, `$2` etc, liek this:

```
awk '/^INSTANCE/ {print \$2}'
```

OR your CMD variable:

```
cmd="/opt/aws/bin/ec2-run-instances -O $secid  -W $seckey $ami  -n $1 -g $secg -k $sshkey -t $instsize -z $2 | awk '/^INSTANCE/ {print \$2}'"
```

Comment: Running that is generating the error I ran into already: WARNING:  Ignoring extra parameter(s): [ |, awk, '/^INSTANCE/, {print, $2}' ]

Comment: @Publiccert: Following prints correct output for me: `cmd="date '+$1' | awk '{print \$2}'" && eval $cmd`

Comment: As @RomanNewaza said, that is not correct usage of the CLI args. It blows up horribly in the format you mention in your comment.

Comment: @Publiccert: Your comment is really funny, its not me but you in your question trying to store these piped commands in a variable `cmd` with all the `$1` and `$2` etc.

Comment: Knock my style all you want. I was the newbie asking for help.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
cmd="/opt/aws/bin/ec2-run-instances -O $secid  -W $seckey $ami  -n $1 -g $secg -k $sshkey -t $instsize -z $2 | awk -v var=$2 '/^INSTANCE/ {print var}'
```

Comment: I'll try this shortly but +1 just for the clever variable manipulation. Thanks. EDIT: Sadly, that seems to have caused a pretty horrific error from AWS side. I'm not entirely sure why. Filled my screen and over ran the buffer I had for that SSH session :P Was fun to watch.

Comment: @Publiccert Sorry about that. Glad you found a solution though! :)

Comment: Not a problem. Thanks for the effort :)